# Do I need to use PHP to send CURL commands?

Tags: php, curl

Good day,

I'm trying to find a way to refresh a token for my home automation system using its API (api.myfox.me) and the only thing I got from the developers is the following information :

> Refreshing an expired access_token To get a new access token, the
>   refresh token is needed.

```
curl -u CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET https://api.myfox.me/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN'
```

A response should look like this :

> {"access_token":"ec8d65d99597b57923c71ca7d05340a71a308f61","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null,"refresh_token":"686a57c4401fe275d64633987d50cab6d86c0960"}

Now, for my question, do I need to use PHP to get this or is there an easier way to retrieve a refreshed token code ?

Any hints on this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: no, any post/get method (depending what the server requires) will do

Comment: Thanks for your reply.